# New vertices get created when moving vertices

Tags: vertices, faces, edges

so I haven't used Blender for some weeks now, and I just noticed that whenever I try to move a vertex, edge or face, a new one gets created ( as if I was kind of extruding, it happens to every single one). Btw, I can do it as many times as i want to any vertex/face/edge. It's difficult to explain, so I'll just put up some images, I might have changed a setting sometime, but I couldn't find which one, and I would prefer not to reset the preferences as I have quite a few add ons installed. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

[image: Here I moved some edges and faces as you can see (these are no duplicates, they get created everytime)][image]

Comment: You say it's not doubles, but that seems to be the only possibility here (likely from extruding the top loop of faces and pressing **Esc** or **RMB**). Have you tried selecting everything and merging by distance?

Comment: Yes, so it does seem to be doubles. But it is strange because I payed attention to my keystrokes, and I dont understand how they appear everytime everywhere, because I myself am not typing 2 times or else. Does anyone have an idea on this one?